# TCP Server async in WebService

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, web-services, tcp

Im implementing a WebService with TCP. The webservice is the Server side that accept multiple clients. Is there any suggestions on how to configure a default port where to start the tcp clients? And with every client connected (aprox. 10 clients) will have an assigned port.

(I'm using Visual Studio 2010 the language is c#, Here is a code block for accepting the clients.)
Any suggestions will be accepted. Thanks!

```
 private void StartListening(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //Will move one the array of threads
        index++;

        //Will get the current IP Address
        IPAddress ipaddr = IPAddress.Any;

        //Port where the data will pass.
        //First Port in use. 10,000
        int Port = 10000;


        if (true)
        {
            _TCPListener = new TcpListener(ipaddr, Port);
            Port = Port + 1;

            //Start Listening
            _TCPListener.Start();
            ThreadStart.Add(new ThreadStart(() => _TCPListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(CompleteAcceptClient, _TCPListener)));
            Thread.Add(new Thread(ThreadStart[index]));
            Thread[index].Start();
        }
        else
        {
            _TCPListener = new TcpListener(ipaddr, Port + 2);
            _TCPListener.Start();

            ThreadStart delegateT = new ThreadStart(() => _TCPListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(CompleteAcceptClient, _TCPListener));
            Thread T = new Thread(delegateT);
            T.Start();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

//Here is the accept client method.

```
private void CompleteAcceptClient(IAsyncResult iar)
    {
        TcpListener tcpl = (TcpListener)iar.AsyncState;
        try
        {
            ThreadStart delegateR = new ThreadStart(() => _TCPClient = tcpl.EndAcceptTcpClient(iar));
            Thread R = new Thread(delegateR);
            R.Start();


            mRx = new byte[1024];
            _TCPClient.GetStream().BeginRead(mRx, 0, mRx.Length, onCompleteReadFromTCPClientStream, _TCPClient);

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            throw e;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is there a specific Reason why you want to use a different port for every single client?

Comment: You would normally have *one* listener port. Note that `EndAcceptTcpClient` returns a *new* TCP Client for each client that connects and its that that is used for all subsequent communications.

Comment: Already resolved it. I used a class where all the methods where declared for the listener to accept clients. And that method is called every time I use a WebMethod. So, I use a port for each client requesting a service.


Also, is there a way to close the port after using it?